# XPATH help for web scraper

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, xpathnavigator

I need to create a button in Web Scraping Chrome Extension to grab data from a web page but I cant get the next page button to work

```
<div class="on" onclick="javascript:djxtablePage(&quot;_djxid_followup_status_&quot;,1)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

When you click next button > the code changed to the following

```
<div class="on" onclick="javascript:djxtablePage(&quot;_djxid_followup_status_&quot;,2)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

Div around the buttons

```
<div class="dxpaging"> </div>
```

But I have got it to go forward > and then backwords as it only selects the active button at the start.. XPATH works but as per image it only goes the the 1st active button as there is 4 buttons.

[image]

```
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "on", " " ))]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get **all the buttons** use XPATH:

```
//*[@class='on'][@onclick]
```

To get **all the buttons**, if there may another class than `on` added to the element, use XPATH:

```
//*[contains(@class,'on')][@onclick]
```

To get **Button 1**:

```
//*[@class="on"][contains(@onclick, '1')]
```

To get **Button 2**:

```
//*[@class="on"][contains(@onclick, '2')]
```

Above XPaths work on code:

```
<div>
    <div class="on" onclick="javascript:djxtablePage(&quot;_djxid_followup_status_&quot;,1)">Button 1</div>
    <div class="on" onclick="javascript:djxtablePage(&quot;_djxid_followup_status_&quot;,2)">Button 2</div>
</div>
```